# UTF-8 html5 webpage encoding

Tags: php, apache, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to grasp UTF-8 and charset encoding in general, but it's tricky

This code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
<title>UTF-8 test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>UTF-8 æøå tést Señor!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
UTF-8 ��� t�st Se�or!
```

Same result on both local server and on multiple public sites (all Apache)
Do I need to change something in php? Or Apache? Or my text editor? (notepad++)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text editor isn't saving as UTF-8.

Comment: So simple it hurts. Damn, I've been reading and trying many guides on how to fix php/apache encoding. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change the character encoding of your notepad++, you can change this under "Encoding" menu.

you can check your right corner of status bar for the encoding of your file.

Comment: Right, but note that for existing data, you need to select the command (in the Encoding menu of Notepad++) for *converting* to UTF-8 format. For new files, it is sufficient to initially set encoding to UTF-8. You can also set (in Settings) the default encoding for new files to UTF-8.

Comment: @Jukka I just selected "code in UTF-8" (not convert) in the existing file, and it switched and worked.